# ionic css - Trying to center elements in a div that is in line with an image

Tags: css

Basically, I have an ion-list with an ion-item that has an image and some information.

It should look something like this:

```
********** ******************************
*        * *           Info             *
*  img   * *            Div             *
*        * *                            *
********** ******************************
```

However I am having issues getting the info-div to line up in the middle.  I have a code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPbQNZ but cannot get it to work :(

Comment: change the image to display:inline-block; and give it a vertical-align:middle;

Comment: give the image vertical align?  i inspected the dimensions and it seems it is in the middle of the item-content.

Comment: actually I got it!  I used transform: translate(0,-50%) and gave top:50%

Comment: vertical align controls the behavior of inline elements. [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/ezxje62s/)

Comment: oooo nice thank you for this example!